# How to prevent script attact in ASP.net MVC project which uses CKEditor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, security, text-editor, ckeditor

In my Asp.net MVC 1.0 application I want to use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) as my Rich Text Editor. But if I want to use this editor i have to **[Disable Request Validation](http://www.superexpert.com/blog/archive/2009/02/20/tip-48-ndash-disable-request-validation.aspx)** . After doing this if I want to display the whole html content directly I can't use HTML.Encode() becuase I want to render the real html content generated from Editor.

So how can we prevent the potential attact from this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [htmlEncodeOutput](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.htmlEncodeOutput) option or use a .Net wrapper like this one: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=15882